about Vertex AI Workbench Executor
pip install fails with Error in Vertex AI Workbench Executor
I am struggling with this issue and need help. Please assist.
I am setting up a notebook environment using a created instance in Google Cloud Vertex AI Workbench. I am trying to run the environment periodically using the executor function, but I encounter an error when running pip install:
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable,
(This is an excerpt from a similar error message.) Reference: pip install failing with NewConnectionError on debian
When I run the code directly in the notebook environment (without using the executor function), the packages install without any issues via pip.
Do you know what might be causing this?

Executor uses infrastructure in Tenant Project, this means that the VM where code runs is in Vertex AI Platform infrastructure. My understanding is they have Public Internet access. Is this pip install a regular library or is a private Repo in your private network?

Thank you your help.
I’m trying to install lightgbm, it’s a regular library.

I tested whether my VM can connect to the Internet. Here are the results:

Executed from the notebook: A response with status 200 was returned, confirming that Public Internet access is available.
Executed from the executor: A ConnectTimeoutError occurred:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443)
As you mentioned, the Vertex AI executor runs in the Tenant Project. My VM can access the Public Internet, but the executor seems to have restrictions.
